# using clock cycles in simplescalar simulator?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, timer, simulator

Am trying to add assembly instructions for timing in pisa architecture using simplescalar simulator. For my instructions i should access clock cycles and store it in the register. This changes has to be made in the machine.def file where all other assembly instructions like add, mul etc are defined.

Am not getting how to access clock cycles in simplescalar simulator? Kindly help

Thank u

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I got it right, but I think you need to keep the PC value. If this is what you want to do, you can see the used definitions in the beginning of the `machine.def` file. NPC for next PC, CPC for current PC and SET_NPC/SET_CPC accordingly. So if you want the PC value, you can have it using CPC. Also these definitions are all set in the simulators' files, for example in `sim-outorder.c`.